# TNS no listener error message in oracle11g, i did not found oracleoraClient11g_home1tnslistener service in my machine

Tags: oracle11g

I have installed Oracle Client when I try to connect Oracle DB receiving a TNS no listener error message, I did not found oracleoraClient11g_home1tnslistener service on my machine. could you please advise on this.

is oracleoraClient11g_home1tnslistener part of Oracle11g Client installation? 
is oracleoraClient11g_home1tnslistener need to be configured manually?

Answer (score 0):

You installed the Client software.

But, is there a database on your computer? If not, you should first install the database and - once you do it - you don't need the Client software because the *Server* already contains all that stuff (and more).

That's what

> I did not found oracleoraClient11g_home1tnslistener service on my machine

suggests - listener is installed along with the database.

If you're in doubt which database to install, I'd suggest the [Oracle 11g Express Edition (XE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) as it is easy to install (in a few <kbd>Next</kbd> clicks), contains a pre-installed HR (Human Resources) schema so you can test your skills immediately, comes with Application Express (Apex) - a really nice piece of software to start with.